# Calling command line program in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to write a program that helps me edit tags of mp3 files. I've made a prototype in python that works, but in C++ I'm having troubles calling the cli program.

What I've done is stored user input in a vector, and I want to send that vector the command line.

```
vector<string> cmd;
cmd.push_back("id3v2");
cmd.push_back("-a " + artist);
cmd.push_back("-t " + trackTitle);
cmd.push_back("-A " + albumTitle);
cmd.push_back("-T " + trackNum);
system(cmd);
```

Comment: You might want to read [a `std::system` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system)?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm still trying to learn, a lot of this doesn't make sense still.

Answer (score 0):

`system()` expects a single `char*` string as input. You need to join your `std::vector` substrings together into a single space-delimited `std::string` and then pass the return value of its `c_str()` method to `system()`.

```
std::string join(const std::vector<std::string> &vec, char delim = ' ')
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    if (!vec.empty())
    {
        oss << vec[0];
        for(size_t idx = 1; idx < vec.size(); ++idx)
            oss << delim << vec[idx];
    }
    return oss.str();
}

...

std::vector<std::string> cmd;
cmd.push_back("id3v2");
cmd.push_back("-a " + artist);
cmd.push_back("-t " + trackTitle);
cmd.push_back("-A " + albumTitle);
cmd.push_back("-T " + trackNum);

system(join(cmd).c_str());
```

Alternatively:

```
std::ostringstream cmd;
cmd << "id3v2";
cmd << " -a " << artist;
cmd << " -t " << trackTitle;
cmd << " -A " << albumTitle;
cmd << " -T " << trackNum;

system(cmd.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to get it to work. Perhaps this isn't the ideal way to accomplish this task, is there a better way to approach this ?

Comment: @tj2jz Just append to a single string instead of using a vector?

Comment: @tj2jz read about pipe handlers (popen) if you want to read output of application